# Rails Controller list if condition is false in another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

i have a problem whit my def in controller

```
  def wait
@evaluations3 = Affiliation.where("go_auth =true") and Affiliation.evaluation.where("ready = false")
```

I want to show only affiliatedes with this 2 conditions = true

Comment: Your english isn't very good which makes it hard to understand this question, especially since it seems to be asking about something which you wouldn't normally do in Rails.  Would you mind adding some more information, and some examples?  That might help.

Comment: and now can u undestand?

Comment: Its my best to explain

Comment: You need to add more information to your question.  At the moment people need to try to reverse-engineer your code to work out what you actually want to do.  You could add your associations for the Affiliation and Evaluation classes.  Say which classes the go_auth and ready fields are in.

Comment: go_auth stay in affiliations and ready stay in evaluation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solve my problem

```
def wait
@evaluations3 = Evaluation.includes(:affiliation).where("go_auth = true").where("ready = false").references(:affiliation)
```

end

Answer (score 0):

From what I am seeing, you have a controller, in which `index` is an action.
In the action, you have a couple of models, on which you are calling a `where` query.

Also, you want to display the objects, where `Affiliation.where("go_auth =true") and Evaluation.where("ready = false")` in the index action.

Look at [Active record query interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)'s Joins. It might provide you a direction.

IMO, you have to try to push your `Affiliation.where("go_auth =true") || Evaluation.where("ready = false")` into a model/ create a PORO which does the same. This will help you in maintaining sanity in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

It's really not clear what you want to do, but **if** the situation is like this:

```
class Affiliation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :evaluation
  #fields - go_auth: boolean

class Evaluation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :affiliations
  #fields - ready: boolean
```

and you want to load Affiliations where go_auth is true and the associated evaluation's ready field is true,then i think this should work

```
@affiliations = Affiliation.include(:evaluation).where(["go_auth = ? and evaluations.ready = ?", true, true])
```

If these aren't your requirements then please say what they are.